# hiding showing elements with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show and hide a text element within a list of items with a :hover function. At the moment I am using the adjacent-sibling selector and what is happening is the text element from the *following div* is being shown, not the one from the currently hovered element.

The css I am using:

```
.product h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.product:hover + .product h3 {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="product">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <span class="price">price</span>
    <a href="source" class="classes"><img src="source" class="classes"></a>
</li>
<li class="product">
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <span class="price">price</span>
    <a href="source" class="classes"><img src="source" class="classes"></a>
</li>
<li class="produc3">
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
    <span class="price">price</span>
    <a href="source" class="classes"><img src="source" class="classes"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So if I hover over the second ´product´ element, Title3 will appear. Any thoughts?

Comment: `.product` isn't corresponding with any class in your HTML, are you sure you're using the correct classes? `.product1` etc.

Comment: There is no element before 'product1 or 2 or 3' with the class `product` so `.product:hover`isn't target anything

Comment: Is not element title2 which sould apear on hojer of product2?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/6d9qyfdd/ ?

Comment: sorry I mislabled the classes, they are all labeled ´product´ no numbers

Comment: thank you @DaniP, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `<li>` classes are not "productx" but "product":

```
.product:hover h3 {
  display: block;
}
```

The h3 is a child of product, not a sibling like you tried to target.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so it was in effect looking not for the child but the next sibling of it…

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean that?

```css
.product h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.product:hover h3 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="product product1">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <span class="price">price</span>
    <a href="source" class="classes"><img src="source" class="classes"></a>
</li>
<li class="product product2">
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <span class="price">price</span>
    <a href="source" class="classes"><img src="source" class="classes"></a>
</li>
<li class="product product3">
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
    <span class="price">price</span>
    <a href="source" class="classes"><img src="source" class="classes"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```